# Why does gcc warn about large alignas value?

Tags: c++, c++14

When compiled with gcc 6.3, this example program

```
#include <array>

class alignas(4096) A {
    std::array<int, 256> array;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
}
```

gives the following warning:

```
3 : <source>:3:21: warning: requested alignment 4096 is larger than 128 [-Wattributes]
 class alignas(4096) A {
                     ^
```

There's no such error with gcc 7.2 though.

[Example](https://godbolt.org/#z: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%2BgOBxCjtH8E0tvGWq18PQQmCYWGIlA2IHS10lp3OxeuLpGd2kj2epFe71Inx%2BogI/2F5EoEPj0PomHwRALyZO/RurukcloqgA7oQEKoPV6fX6A0G9hn5dnc/nCycbRcSxOa/d6y9M0XtntDrftscy7Jnbcz43My3vq2IEhe1DQT24z/GEgi4RFkVRShMV5bEXGIakCSJElyUpakazpVhgEZXlmVZdkuR5GsBSFEUpAJcUyxraVZXfRV2BVARHA1eBtV1PB9SNE0zQtPheGtR47UkUcy3HatRmkZdvV9f1AyCHYuFDcNhyTGNAITKMuBTeit3eK9djvO8DwrY9RNrB4hAbJtug/eBvxAdtOxSMFfwTEBQMHCMR0dKQRJfKcFnk%2BcCEXCTV2k1RZK4bS1lIHM82hOpDNII8q18syngvbdSE2a99NvE4nxPMSzMsrMTkiwrTKi0quWIQQ2KGNwgA%3D)

1. Does it mean that the compiler just informs about alignment being too big? What's the purpose of such a warning?
2. The standard doesn't allow the compiler to ignore this alignment specifier (even in presence of the warning), does it?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is `alignof(std::max_align_t)` equal to your platform?

Comment: I imagine the maximum fundamental alignment isn't 128. My guess is that GCC intends to always support 128 because there is some particular application that requires it, but is warning that they might stop supporting alignments greater than 128 at some point.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat 16.

Answer (score 8):

The standard allows [all sorts of things to break if you `alignas` to larger than that of `std::max_align_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Alignment):

> the largest *fundamental alignment* of any type is the alignment of `std::max_align_t`. If a type's alignment is made stricter (larger) than `std::max_align_t` using `alignas`, it is known as a type with *extended alignment* requirement. A type whose alignment is extended or a class type whose non-static data member has extended alignment is an *over-aligned type*. It is implementation-defined if `new-expression`, `std::allocator::allocate`, and `std::get_temporary_buffer` support over-aligned types. Allocators instantiated with over-aligned types are allowed to fail to instantiate at compile time, to throw `std::bad_alloc` at runtime, to silently ignore unsupported alignment requirement, or to handle them correctly.

Basically, you can declare highly aligned types, but some stuff might break when you use them; it's possible GCC6 is being conservative, or it might actually fail for some of the specified cases mentioned above and it's trying to warn you.

Comment: but the structure/class itself is guaranteed to be properly aligned, even if _some things_ could be broken, is that correct?

Comment: Truth be told, however, this is also true for alignments of 16, 32, 64, or 128 which GCC6 _doesn't_ warn about (`std::max_align_t` being `alignof(long long)` which is 8). I guess that was just a compiler defect, which is why GCC7 doesn't produce the warning, too. Scary thought that anything that is properly aligned for SSE/AVX is factually allowed to fail silently, though...