# Aligned allocation of elements in vector

Tags: c++, vector, boost, memory-alignment

I need to have elements in a `std::vector` aligned to some given step in memory. For example, in the program as follows:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct __attribute__((aligned(256))) A
{
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> as(10);
    std::cout << &as[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << &as[1] << std::endl;
}
```

I would expect that the last two digits in printed numbers will be ‘00’.

In practice, I see that it is true in Visual Studio 2019, and in gcc 8+. But can I be absolutely sure, or is it just a coincidence and some custom allocator in `std::vector` (like `boost::alignment::aligned_allocator`) is necessary?

Comment: In Visual Studio instead of __attribute__ there shall be __declspec(align(256))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In practice, I see that it is true in Visual Studio 2019, and in gcc 8+. But can I be absolutely sure, or is it just a coincidence and some custom allocator in `std::vector` (like `boost::alignment::aligned_allocator`) is necessary?

There is no reason to expect that, provided the absence of bugs in the implementation of the respective compiler (which can however be checked on the assembly level, if required).

Since C++11, there is the [`alignas`-specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) which allows you to enforce the alignment in a standardized way. Consequently, the standard allocator will call `operator new` upon calling `allocator::allocate()`, to which it will forward the alignment information according to the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new). Thus, the standard allocator already respects alignment needs, if specified. However, of course if the global `operator new` is overloaded by a custom implementation, no such guarantee can be made.

Comment: Unfortunately, gcc 5 and clang 5 fail the above code example: vector elements are not aligned to 256 bytes there. So it seems that boost::alignment::aligned_allocator is required at least for older compilers?

Comment: @Fedor Generally, you must make sure that your aligment is less strict than `alignof(std::max_align_t)`, otherwise you work with *over-aligned* types for which the standard also allows to ignore the alignment alltogether. See also (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070361/why-does-gcc-warn-about-large-alignas-value). For such cases, the boost allocator might help.